# How to create an NBT file for a spawner in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I create an NBT file for a spawner in minecraft? If I already have the spawner in a world, how can I extract that as an NBT file for use in other things?

Comment: Do you want an "NBT file" (how NBT data is stored, readable with an NBT editor) or the text that you would type into a command to create that block (human-readable plaintext, looks similar to JSON).

Comment: The actual NBT file itself. I would like to use it for McDungeon for custom spawners. That program reads in NBT files to generate spawners.

Answer (score 0):

[Structure blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block) can allow you to select an area, and export it as a NBT file.

[image: An image of structure blocks being used to save a creeper spawner]

The saved .NBT file will contain all of the information for the blocks, entities and tile-entities within that region:

[image: An image of NBTExplorer showing the saved structure file]

A tool such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) will let you move these tags up to root and delete everything else, to have an NBT file containing only the tags of the spawner:

[image: An image of NBTExplorer showing the saved structure file, this time with the tags for the spawner moved to the NBT root]

If you're not in 1.10 yet, you may need to make a copy of the world and open that in 1.10 to use structure blocks.